# Compile time Error in ProC (Embedded sql in C)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-pro-c

Please tell me whats wrong with the query. I am using Pro C.

```
EXEC SQL SELECT 1
        INTO    :db_count
        FROM    sachin t
        WHERE   t.serialno =   :serial_no
        AND     t.amount = (:db_inamount - (SELECT NVL(overrun_amount,0)
                                            FROM  sunny tovrun
                                            WHERE tovrun.serialno = :serial_no
                                            AND   tovrun.timestamp = t.timestamp
                                            AND   rownum < 2)
                            )
        AND     t.request_code = 11
        AND     t.reason_code = 0
        AND     t.reversed    = 0
        AND rownum < 2;
```

And getting the compilation errors

```
Syntax error at line 4487, column 42, file my_file.pc:
Error at line 4487, column 42 in file my_file.pc            AND             t.amount = (:db_inamount - (SELECT NVL(overrun_amount,0)
```

Comment: What about using `AND t.amount = (SELECT :db_amount - NVL(overrun_amount, 0) ...`

Comment: Man db_amount is a variable and not a column name

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm suggesting a computed column

Comment: @OMG, It worked. Could you please explain me the teason behind this

Comment: Try to give more informative titles than "Compile time Error in <programming language>".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 AND t.amount = (SELECT :db_amount - NVL(overrun_amount, 0) ...
```

It's a standard computed column, where the value is calculated prior to the comparison to the `t.amount` value for equality.

Comment: Yes thats true, but I want to know why AND t.amount = (SELECT :db_amount - NVL(overrun_amount, 0) worked and (:db_inamount - (SELECT NVL(overrun_amount,0) from table ) doesnot.

Comment: The latter is a scalar subquery expression, which was introduced back in 8i. But those 'modern' features aren't understood by the SQL parser in the pre-compiler. OMG's solution is a simpler subquery syntax supported since wayback.